# How to assign text to Field codes

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

Aside from using a Macro as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1000988/prompt-to-enter-custom-document-property-in-microsoft-word) or the very clumsy '[Advanced Property](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_s2jU7girbyM/SWC5WzrU8II/AAAAAAAABVg/mmXLeGLrjvA/s400/dnd_DocProp2.JPG)' Dialogue how can a simple user populate/add/set the value of a field code?

I have a document with cover page and the following field codes:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY  Title2 }
{ DOCPROPERTY  Title3 }
```

These are then repeated on the header / footer of the following pages.

How can a simple user update these field codes? I'd like to avoid using a Macro or telling them to go into the advanced properties window.

Are there other options?

My best solution so far is to use a [Macro as suggested above](https://superuser.com/questions/1000988/prompt-to-enter-custom-document-property-in-microsoft-word) but *.docm* is a no-no.

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't get it to work. https://superuser.com/questions/553731/ms-word-meta-data-update/554112

Comment: FWIW (old question!) I don't think the link you referenced is really relevant. If you have no alternative but to use Custom Document Properties, it's difficult to avoid the barriers that Microsoft now puts in your way. You *might* be able to do something using Content Controls mapped to a CustomXML datastore. In really simple cases, or if your documents are stored on Sharepoint,  you might be able to do that without VBA. Even in slightly more complicated situations, you might be able to *set up* your document using VBA, then distribute the resulting .docx.